# Highlight selected table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem implementing something in a drag and drop function. So far draggable and sortable is ok. Right now the problem is I'm trying to highlight the selected row and delete it using button.

I have two tables: class A and class UI. I managed to highlight the `tr` table class A. However in table class UI I can't highlight the `tr`.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwb7vy9L/).

I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: `$('tbody tr').not(this)` can be swapped with `$(this).siblings()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had several issues with your code and CSS:

first issue - Your test2 CSS selector was set only to work under table with class A:

your code:

```
.A tbody tr.test2 td {
    background: rgba(20, 111, 186, 0.38);
}
```

my fix, be generic:

```
tbody tr.test2 td {
    background: rgba(20, 111, 186, 0.38);
}
```

next issue, your click was never called on 2nd table:
your code (only under table with ID diagram):

```
$('#diagram tbody tr').click(function(e) {
    $('#diagram tbody tr').not(this).removeClass('test2');
    $(this).toggleClass('test2');
});
```

my code (event delegation for all tables):

```
$('tbody').on("click","tr",function(e) {
    $('tbody tr').not(this).removeClass('test2');
    $(this).toggleClass('test2');
});
```

working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jwb7vy9L/9/

working fiddle with delete:

```
$("#button1").on("click",function(e){
    $("table:not(.A) .test2").remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jwb7vy9L/14/

Comment: Umm i know how to that.. But right now the purpose highlight in table UI is for delete function.  I don't want table A row deletable. That why i'm trying to separate them.

Comment: but Saar i dont want the table A row,  can be delete. Do you know how to control that?

Comment: added :not(.A) so now A is not deleted

Comment: I love you man! .. Where you  learn all this code. Please teach me master :D

Comment: from stackoverflow :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92446/discussion-between-saar-and-fiido-firdauz).

Comment: c'mon seriously man haha. Do you have any suggestion a good website to learn JS and JQuery? Please beside stackoverflow T_T

Comment: you can  delete just hetag tr inside the '#diagram1'  $('#button1').on('click',function(){ $('#diagram1 tbody tr.test2').remove(); });

Answer (score 0):

You want to control the tables separated? Maybe this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwb7vy9L/10/) can help you

html

```
<table class="A" id="diagram">
    <tbody id="sortable2">
   <tr class="new-item"> 
       <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="new-item"> 
       <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="new-item"> 
       <td>3</td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<br><br>

<table class="UI" id="diagram1" >
    <tbody id="sortable">

     </tbody>
</table>

 <br><br>   

<button id="button1">Clear selected row in Table class UI</button>
```

javascript

```
test();

$("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.item.hasClass("new-item")) {
            // This is a new item

        }
    }
});
$(".new-item").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        test();
    },
    zIndex: 10000
});

/** Highlight Statement **/
function test(){
    $('#diagram tbody tr').unbind('click').bind('click',function(e) {
        $('#diagram tbody tr').not(this).removeClass('test2');
        $(this).toggleClass('test2');
    });

    $('#diagram1 tbody tr').unbind('click').bind('click',function(e) {
        $('#diagram1 tbody tr').not(this).removeClass('test2');
        $(this).toggleClass('test2');
    });
}
```

CSS

```
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:200px;
}

tbody tr.test2 td {
    background: rgba(20, 111, 186, 0.38);
}
```

Comment: why 2 functions for doing the same thing?

Comment: For some reason, when I change https to http works. Please try again

Comment: Saar, to control the two tables separated

Comment: so extract the function and call it from the 2 handlers, no need to write the function twice

Comment: @alexqoliveira So how i'm going to use delete function? I don't want the table A row can be deletable. Delete button only for table UI row.

Comment: Thanks for your help @alexqoliveira i already got the answer :)